# Co-Occurrence Without Using Matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve the co-occurrence problem without using a matrix.  So I take in a text file and lowercase all characters, strip punctuation, split into a list.  Then for every word on line one I want that word in a dictionary with the word being the key and the line number being the value.  Then for line two I want the word to be the key and the line number two to be the value, etc, etc.  I cannot figure out how to get the value to increment to what the line number is.  I've tried unsuccessfully to do a for loop.  I can't figure out how to make a while loop accumulator as I'm not sure what exactly I can compare x <,>,etc too.  len(ofdict) doesn't work, len(list) doesn't work; I'm not sure what I need.  I've been stuck for like 7 hours.

```
import re
import string
string.punctuation


def open_file(f):
    with open(input("Enter a file name: "),'r' ) as inf:

  #
    while 1:
        f = inf.readline()
        f = f.lower()
        f = re.sub(r'\b\w{1,2}\b', '', f)
        f = "".join(i for i in f if i not in string.punctuation)
        print_list([f])

        if not f: 
            break
  #

def print_list(f):
    f = list(filter(None, f))
    for k in range(0, len(f)):
    l = (f[k])
    l = l.strip('  ')
    l = l.strip()
    read_data(l)
#

def read_data(l):
    l = [l]
    l = [x for x in l if x != '']
    d = list(filter(None, l))
    print_list2(d)

def print_list2(f):
    l = 0  
for k in range(0, len(f)):

    my_dictionary = f[k]
    word = my_dictionary.split()

    this_dic = {word[k] : {l} for k in range(0, len(word))}
    print(this_dic)












r = open_file(input("Press Any Key To Begin: You Will Enter A File Name 
During\The Next Prompt "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found.  Basically I was trying to while loop past when I should of.  The idea is to while loop while utilizing the readline method.  Then pass the result as a parameter into later functions until you need to set the values of the dictionary.

```
import re
import string
string.punctuation


def open_file(f):
    with open(input("Enter a file name: "),'r' ) as inf:


  #
    lines = 0
    while 1:
        lines += 1
        f = inf.readline()
        f = f.lower()
        f = re.sub(r'\b\w{1,2}\b', '', f)
        f = "".join(i for i in f if i not in string.punctuation)

        print_list([f], lines)

        if not f: 
            break
  #

def print_list(f, lines):
    f = list(filter(None, f))
    for k in range(0, len(f)):
        l = (f[k])
        l = l.strip('  ')
        l = l.strip()
        read_data(l, lines)
#

def read_data(l, lines):
    l = [l]
    l = [x for x in l if x != '']
    d = list(filter(None, l))
    print_list2(d, lines)

def print_list2(f, lines):

    for k in range(0, len(f)):

        my_dictionary = f[k]
        word = my_dictionary.split()

        this_dic = {word[k] : {lines} for k in range(0, len(word))}
        print(this_dic)












r = open_file(input("Press Any Key To Begin: You Will Enter A File Name During\
                The Next Prompt "))
```